# How do I install the Ralink RT3070 wireless driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, compiling

I bought an AZTECH WL562USB wireless adapter and am stuck trying to install the driver.

The driver file I downloaded is a BZ2, called

`2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.bz2`

How can I install the driver from this bz2 file?

Answer (score 3):

I found this workaround that worked for me:

This is how I got my RT5370 usb wifi adapter installed and working on CB2.

1. download driver archive

   2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2 .5.0.3_DPO.bz2 (RT8070/RT3070/RT3370/RT5370/RT5372 USB 03/28/2012 2.5.0.3
2. unpack the archive and navigate into the top level directory just extracted:

   ```
   tar jxvf  2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.bz2
   cd 2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
   ```
3. modify the following code in `os/linux/config.mk` as below:

   ```
   HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
   HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
   WFLAGS += -DCONFIG_STA_SUPPORT
   ```
4. to quieten down the debugging modify `sta/sta-cfg.c`:

   ```
   remove "#ifdef DBG" on line 4095
   remove "endif /* DBG */" on line 4693
   ```
5. to change the name from ra0 to wlan0 modify `include/rtmp_def.h` and change `ra` to `wlan` in the following lines:

   ```
   #define INF_MAIN_DEV_NAME        "ra"
   #define INF_MBSSID_DEV_NAME        "ra"
   ```
6. make and install the modified driver

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe rt5370sta
   ```
7. reboot and check with `lsusb` `lsmod` and `ifconfig` to make sure all is working as required in the operating system.

The CB2 setup program didn't work for me but the xbmc network manager addon worked perfectly so I downloaded and use that rather than doing it all via the operating system.

I hope this helps someone else trying to get an RT5370 wifi adapter up and running.

[Source](http://forum.stmlabs.com/printthread.php?tid=8333)

Comment: This solution probably worked in Linux 2.x, but it fails to compile in Linux 4.15 (Ubuntu 18.04). The source code in the linked archive is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

### How to download, build and install the RT3070 driver

- Your adapter has a Ralink RT3070 chipset. You can download the official Linux drivers from [this site](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501).
- We'll suppose the driver has been downloaded to your *Downloads* folder and is called `2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.bz2`. Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, and type or paste the following:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
  cd Downloads
  tar -xjf 2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
  cd 2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
  sudo make && sudo make install
  make clean
  cd ..
  rm -rf 2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
  ```
- Reboot, and hopefully your wireless connection will appear!

Comment: @user69589 Alternatively you can download the driver direct from the manufacturer of your card [here](http://www.aztech.com/support/downloads/) which you can install following the above steps.

Comment: @MarkRooney That's an older driver.

Comment: You have a dead link. Nevertheless, you can download the driver file from my repo here now: [2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.bz2](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/AlfaWiFiAdapterSoftware/blob/master/ALFA_Driver_DVD_v3.0/driver/Linux_driver/AWUS036NH/2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.bz2).

Comment: When I run `sudo make` I get this error: `make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:232: archscripts] Error 2`

Comment: Same as Gabriel Staples: I get the same error.